# Basement in detached garage required to have two means of egress?

Tags: code-compliance

I have been reading the IBC Code and it is very long and complicated.

The point I am trying to figure out is whether a basement in a detached garage requires two means of egress.

There are whole bunch of conditions that constitute different exceptions to egress requirements. Firstly, if a detached garage is not considered a "dwelling" unit (meaning by its occupancy classification), then that is one issue. One article I read said that a secondary means of egress is needed only in a room where "sleeping is likely to occur". The other is that in IBC at one point it says "garages" require only a single means of egress, so would that apply to the basement of the garage as well? Then in addition to all this there are "occupancy load" questions, etc.

Can anyone can map out the different issues here in different parts of the IBC code and explain how I demonstrate why or why not two egresses are required from a basement in a detached garage?

Comment: I need pictures.   Who has a basement in a garage???   I have never seen it in residential.

Comment: @DMoore -- it's not unheard-of, but not terribly common either because it requires the extra structure for a suspended garage slab

Comment: What is the basement being used for? Shop space? Storage? Some other function?

Comment: Also, does your jurisdiction adopt NFPA 101 (the *Life Safety Code* or LSC for short) in addition to the IBC/IRC?  Keep also in mind that there's a difference between a *means of egress* and a *means of escape*, to use the LSC's terminology here...

Comment: Commonsense would say two exits for safety. If you only had one and were trapped by the fire would you regret not having a second while sitting on your cloud playing your harp?